# Find the row ID for a unique value and print the entire row (Python / Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I am in the process of creating a python script that checks if values exist in a column from a CSV file but not in the other. Currently, I have this functionality working as intended and the script returns the unique values from the column in the CSV file. The next step is to have the script return the entire row of that unique value. So for example, if the user with ID 'A53456' exists in row 15 in the CSV file, I would like the script to come along and print the entire row number 15. Any idea how to implement this? Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd

#create dataframes
dataframe_server_permissions = pd.read_csv("\server_permissions.csv")
dataframe_database_permissions = pd.read_csv("\database_permissions.csv")

#create list from column values 
database_permissions_list=dataframe_database_permissions['Rights'].tolist()   
server_permissions_list=dataframe_server_permissions['Permissions'].tolist()

#remove the duplicate values from the list
server_permissions_list_duplicates_removed = list(set(server_permissions_list))
database_permissions_list_duplicates_removed = list(set(database_permissions_list))

#identify permissions that exist in one file but not the other
set1 = set(database_permissions_list_duplicates_removed)
set2 = set(server_permissions_list_duplicates_removed)
permissions_in_server_but_not_database = list(sorted(set2 - set1))
print(permissions_in_server_but_not_database)

#output the values from the comparison 
number_of_records_from_permissions_in_server_but_not_database = len(permissions_in_server_but_not_database)
print(number_of_records_from_permissions_in_server_but_not_database)
i = 0
while i < number_of_records_from_permissions_in_server_but_not_database:
print(permissions_in_server_but_not_database[i])
i += 1
```

Comment: Share your dummy data frame please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example, without loops, using only `pandas` and `numpy` (much faster then loops)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,1,22,3], 'B':[1,2,33,1,2,3]})

    A   B
0   1   1
1   2   2
2   3  33
3   1   1
4  22   2
5   3   3

# find the common values, so we can later exclude them 
# and get only unique values
common_values = np.intersect1d(df['A'].unique(), df['B'].unique())
print(common_values)
[1 2 3]

# '~' is a NOT operator
# unique values from column 'A':
df[~df['A'].isin(common_values)]

    A   B
4   22  2

# unique values from column 'B':
df[~df['B'].isin(common_values)]

    A   B
2   3   33
```

Comment: I don't think this answers OP's question

Comment: I see what I need to do now, create a list for each column in my CSV file. I tried adding an additional column "C" and "D" and got the desired output as follows. Thanks for your help!
    A   B   C   D
2  3  33  54  22